# Excel Print sheets from array

Tags: arrays, excel, printing, vba

I want to select a array of sheets using the Sheets(Array()) method. The sheets I want to select are named in the cells of my workheet Printlijst. The sheetnames are listed form column D to K.

Not all cells are filled so if I use the folowing function

This is what the sheet looks like: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJqZc.jpg

And this is the code:

```
Sub PDF_maken()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim Mypath As String
Dim strarray As String


Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printlijst")
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In ws.Range("B20:B20").Cells

If Not IsEmpty("B" & r.Row) Then
Mypath = ws.Range("B" & r.Row).Text

colCheck = 4
Do Until Cells(r.Row, colCheck) = ""
    strarray = strarray & IIf(colCheck > 4, ",", "") & Cells(r.Row, colCheck).Value
colCheck = colCheck + 1
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SelectedSheets.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Mypath & ws.Range("C" & r.Row).Text & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


End If
Next r

End Sub
```

The errors happens when more than one sheet must be selected 
When I use the errorcheck strarray is "2450,2451,2452,2453,2454,2455,2456,2457"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `strarray` in `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray)`. It is expecting a single sheet name or a collection of sheets in array.

Is this what you are trying?

```
'
'~~> Rest of your code
'

Dim strarray  As String
Dim MyAr As Variant

Do Until Cells(r.Row, colCheck) = ""
    strarray = strarray & IIf(colCheck > 4, ",", "") & Cells(r.Row, colCheck).Value
    colCheck = colCheck + 1
Loop

If InStr(1, strarray, ",") Then
    MyAr = Split(strarray, ",") '<~~ This is where we are creating an actual array

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(MyAr).Select
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray).Select
End If

'
'~~> Rest of your code
'
```

**NOTE**: BTW, you should avoid using `.Select` and directly perform the operation on those sheet(s). You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, the sheets stored in the array are selected. Only problem now is that when multiple sheets are selected the exporting command does not work. When only one sheet must be printed it does work :)

Comment: When you are exporting multiple sheets then you can use `Selection` after the `.Select`. However ensure that all those sheets are unhidden else the `.Select` command will give an error. `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename......`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? I may not be able to answer in the next 12 hours as I am about to hit the sack. But i will look at it in the morning when I wake up :)

Comment: property or method not supported by the object

Comment: When I use the following code to print it does work however     `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(MyAr).Select
       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Range("D" & r.Row).Text).Activate
        
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False `

Comment: After the line `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray).Select` in the next line type this and then try.

`Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= Mypath & ws.Range("C" & r.Row).Text & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False`

Ensure that `Mypath & ws.Range("C" & r.Row).Text` has a valid value

Comment: I think there is something wrong with te path. It is a bit long. We I shorten the pathname it does work. Thanks a lot